# UIPopoverPresentationController popover displays over the entire view

Tags: swift, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to create a rightBarButtonItem that appears throughout my app.  When this barItem is clicked I want to show a modal popup using UIPopoverPresentationController.  I have been able to get the button to show up on the barItem on all the views.  However when i click on the button the xib takes over the entire view (including nav bar, see image below).  Please see the class below:

```
class MyAppsNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = Colors.Red01.color()
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ellipsis"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(displayMenu(sender:)))
    }

    func displayMenu(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        let filterVC =  DropdownMenuController(nibName: "DropdownMenuController", bundle: nil)
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: filterVC)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        //nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        nav.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)

        let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController! as UIPopoverPresentationController
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = .up
        popover.delegate = self
        popover.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
        popover.sourceView = self.view;
        var frame:CGRect = (sender.value(forKey: "view")! as AnyObject).frame
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y+20
        popover.sourceRect = frame

        popover.delegate = self
        self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```

Result when clicked on the button:

[image: First view with rightBarButtonImage]

When clicked the popup takes over entire view:

[image: When clicked the popup takes over entire view]

Comment: Try changing `UIModalPresentationStyle.popover` to `UIModalPresentationStyle.custom`.

Comment: Is the `DropdownMenuController` size being set in the nib?

Comment: @William GP: I have set the view to show as Alignment Rectangle and the width=300, height=400.  Still same result.

Comment: @dfd: tried with custom but getting same result.

Comment: Here's what I have - (a) `UIButton` on a `UIViewController` (more than one - it's an "info" popup for purchases) that (b) presents a second `UIViewController` and view, that (c) takes up 80% of the screen, with (d) the other 20% "muted" (think "greyed out"). My entire app "religiously" uses auto layout, is universal, and works in all orientations *and* doesn't use IB. I *think* this sounds like your issue. If so, let me know. I don't see where you are using frames. EDIT: I also have a navigation bar (in my IB storyboard) showing on this screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you're not using the right delegate method? I think this looks better:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Also, in this case sourceView and sourceRect is not needed: specifying a barButtonItem for the popover presentation controller is sufficient.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622314-barbuttonitem

Comment: Thank you so much @Adam.  That was it.  I changed it to the function you suggested (adaptivePresentationStyle).  I also had to change the line below:
From: popover.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
To: popover.barButtonItem = sender

Comment: do you know why the navigation bar appears in the popup?  do i have to manually hide it in viewWillAppear and unhide it in viewWillDisappear method of the tableview controller that is shown as popup?  in the popup I have a home button.  when i clicked on it navigates to home page within a popup instead of the main view.

Comment: Got it to work.  I had to capture and pass around the navigation controller.  One issue i still have is that when the pop up appears it does not gray out the presenting view controller.  How do I force this?